# n_dead_tup vs n_tup_del in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

What is the difference between `n_dead_tup` vs `n_tup_del` in `pg_stat_all_tables`?

What I understand is `n_dead_tup` shows the number of tuples that were deleted and the old tuples that were deleted as part of updates.

How does `n_tup_del` differ from `n_dead_tup`. I am able to clear the `n_dead_tup` to zero after doing vacuum and I have some count in `n_tup_del`

Comment: A dead one will be cleaned up by vacuum (autovacuum), it's the amount of work that the database has to do at some point. The deleted tuples are just a statistic. An update can also result in a dead tuple, the old version of the tuple.

Comment: In Postgres an update is essentially a delete of an old tuple and an insert of new one. This means update and delete both can create tuples that are then marked dead and are eligible for being vacuumed away.  `n_dead_tup` shows those tuples. `n_tup_del` and `n_tup_upd ` show the number of  rows acted on by delete and update respectively that combined created `n_dead_tup`.

Comment: I should have added to my previous comment the [HOT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-hot.html) exception for updates where old tuples will be removed as part of the update. That is tracked in `n_tup_hot_upd `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n_tup_del is permanent cumulative count (until reset, or a crash).  n_dead_tup is a current counter which gets decremented by vacuum. It also gets incremented by updates, and by inserts and updates which abort.